# Rails: authentication system based on external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm building a Rails application to extend features of an existing online Rails app. The existing Rails app provides an API for authentication.

My approach: user X have an account at the existing Rails app. With these login data the user X should authenticate on my Rails app. The existing app offers a gem to connect to the API after login.

Whats the best method to store the information about a successful login? Should i use sessions? Or does Rails offer better methods for this?

Comment: What kind of authentication is it? OAuth? OAuth2? Home-grown?

Comment: Here are further details: https://github.com/yolk/mite-rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Rails offers a standard method for this.

You can store user_id in session after successful authentication, then check `session[:user_id]` in application_controller on each request to see if the user has logged in or not.

See [#250 Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) on RailsCasts.